# How do you calculate the relative probability using a Monte Carlo simulation?

Tags: octave

We are supposed to plot a graph, on octave, of the relative probability and cumulative probability of picking a two of spades from a deck of cards.  Relative probability=number of successes observed so far/number of experiments run so far, while cumulative probability = number of successes run so far/N where N is the number of experiments run (in this case N=10000 and N=100000).  I have already determined the number of successes observed by using the random function on octave. However, I don't understand how to obtain the number of experiments run so far.

Comment: How many random numbers have you drawn? That’s your number of experiments.

Comment: Your description doesn't make much sense, which I think is probably part of the problem. I think you may be using language that isn't helping with your understanding, particularly where you say N=10000 but also N=100000. I suspect what you really mean is that you're running 10,000 simulations, where each simulation consists of performing 100,000 draws. In which case the probability obtained at each experiment is simply the number of times one obtains a 'two of spades' after 100,000 draws, and then you choose to represent how this progresses over all experiments in a relative or cumulative way.